# How can test real access right for other User-Account in powershell

Tags: powershell, rights

I need to try if a specific user has read or write acces on DFS Folder (to validate my DFS).

I am Admin on the domain and I have the credential of this user in $Credentials
but Test-Path, Get-Item, New-Item do not accept the credential

Comment: hello check ntfs perm for get-item must have "list folder content" permission , for new-item must have "modify" permission with get-acl command

Comment: I nead a real test not juste check the right on End level (file), because good right a neaded on each parent directory.

Comment: dude check this `get-childitem "C:\windows\temp" -recurse | get-acl | Format-List` this simple code recursively give you permission if you something like this tell me i clear for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead check acl recursively, i use real write access with [`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh849848%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) and specific credential (`start-process` is an alias of `runas`).
the process write a new file with $(whoami) content
after ending process check if file exist and his content.

```
function test-Write ($folder)
    $WinCredential = Get-Credential -UserName "Domain\User" -Message "Login"
    Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait -Credential $WinCredential -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "whoami | out-file '$folder\test.txt'"
    if ((get-content "$folder\test.txt") -like "Domain\User") {
       return 'OK'
    }
    return 'Erreur NTFS Access'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) for running commands in the context of a different user:

```
$computer = 'localhost'
$cred     = Get-Credential

Invoke-Command -Computer $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
  Param($path)

  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $path) {
    New-Item -ItemType File "$path\your.txt"
  }
} -ArgumentList 'C:\some\folder'
```

You could also use [`Start-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx), but that would run the scriptblock in the background, so it'd mean more management overhead.

Another option, if everything else fails, might be `runas.exe`, although it may require some [creative quoting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/04/28/how-can-i-use-the-runas-command-to-run-a-script-under-alternate-user-credentials.aspx):

```
& runas /user:DOM\username "powershell -Command \`"&{ New-Item 'C:\some\folder\your.txt' }`"\"
```

If you just need to check the permissions on a given folder without performing an action, you'd use [`Get-Acl`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849802.aspx):

```
Get-Acl 'C:\some\folder' |
  select -Expand Access |
  ? { $_.IdentityReference -like '*\username' }
```

Comment: my user are not autorized to use invoke-command (is juste domain user)

Comment: @Alban Without admin privileges you cannot impersonate other users.

Comment: my personnal user acount is Admin but the user in $credential is just a simple user on a domain

Comment: I have good result with Start-Job but PS display many error on running process ([localhost] error on runing process in backgroup. 
Error : username or password incorrect.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2147467259,PSSessionStateBroken)

Comment: @Alban If `Invoke-Command` fails you could try `runas` instead (see updated answer). As for the error you got from the job: that indicates an authentication failure (username or password incorrect). Check your credentials. For further debugging you'd need to show the actual code causeing the error and provide more information about how the DFS folder is connected to the host where the code is run.

Comment: runas is an alias as start-process and it works, thanks : 
Start-Process -Credential $cred -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList 'whoami | out-file d:\your.txt'